# Redirect user depending on user type at login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, redirect

I've got two controllers: admin and customers, plus one more called sessions for handling login and authentication. I'm trying to use one login form so that when an admin logs in, they are redirected to their part of the site, and if a customer logs in, they are taken to their part.

Edit: changed the params to login by email, but now getting the error No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"customers"} when I try to log in as a customer :S!!

Code:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

 def new
 end

 def create
   user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
   customer = Customer.find_by_email(params[:email])

   if user and user.authenticate(params[:password])
     session[:user_id] = user.id
     redirect_to admin_url

   elsif customer and customer.authenticate(params[:password])
     session[:customer_id] = customer.id
     redirect to customer_url  

   else
     redirect_to login_url, alert: "Invalid user/password combination"
 end


end

 def destroy
   session[:user_id] = nil
   session[:customer_id] = nil
   redirect_to store_url, notice: "Logged out"
 end
end
```

Code for the login page (stored in app/sessions/new.html.erb):

```
<div class="depot_form">
<% if flash[:alert] %>
    <p id="notice"><%= flash[:alert] %></p>
<% end %>

<%= form_tag do %>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Please Log In</legend>

    <div>
        <%= label_tag :email, 'Email:' %>
        <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
    </div>

    <div>
        <%= label_tag :password, 'Password:' %>
        <%= password_field_tag :password, params[:password] %>
    </div>

    <div>
        <%= submit_tag "Login" %>
    </div>
</fieldset>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

Also, if relevant, I've got this in the config/routes file:

```
controller :sessions do
   get  'login' => :new
   post 'login' => :create
  delete 'logout' => :destroy
end
```

Edit: changed the params to login by email, but now getting the error No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"customers"} when I try to log in as a customer :S!!

Comment: This would probably be easier to debug if you had methods like `User.authenticate` and `Customer.authenticate` to avoid doing so much in your controller. Unit tests are easy to write compared to functional ones.

Comment: Could you add the login view code too?

Comment: I've added it to the OP now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have one login form, then the input for the username/email will either end up in the params hash as either

```
params[:email]
```

or

```
params[:name]
```

But it looks like params[:email] doesn't exist since you're only using one form. Since you can successfully authenticate as an admin, I would guess that the input for the username is titled "name", so in your params hash, when you authenticate as a customer, your authenticating against

```
params[:name] #this is what I think the input on the form is named
```

instead of

```
params[:email]  #which is what it looks like your code is looking for.
```

Can you post the view code?

Comment: Edit: Upon seeing the view code, this looks to be the case. Matzi is correct, change your code to params[:name] and add a message to customers that they need to use their email address.

Comment: I've changed all the code to ask for the email address instead - and added a migration to the admin db to add an email column. However, now when I log in with a customer email, I'm getting the error: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"customers"}. I apologise, I am new to rails, and I have no idea how to solve this one!! On successful login I want the site to go to the customer index view - I though that's what the sessions controller specifies!?

Comment: In your controller you have `redirect to customer_url`  which would map to a show action (your "showing" a single customer).  Try changing customer_url to customers_path  or customers_url.

Comment: That's got it @entropy_9, thanks! I just assumed that as the admin redirect_to used the same syntax and routed to the index (that is the only view available to it), that it would be the same for the customer action as well. Thanks to everyone else for help too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `params[:email]` does not exist at all! Try using the `params[:name]`, and hope that your customer knows that he has to write his email into the name field.

```
user = User.find_by_name(params[:name])
customer = Customer.find_by_email(params[:name])
```

Comment: Ah! That's probably it! I'll change all of the fields for emails - probably easier to get an admin to log in by email! Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, always be consistent. :)